# Apache fresh installation ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, centos

I've installed Apache on CentOS and have not enabled SSL, and yet I get the following error.

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please. Hint:
https://192.168.1.50/ Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.1.50
Port 443
```

The page I was testing it is a simple html page.

I did not make many changes to the fleshly installed Apache. The only things I edited are IPTABLES config file to allow LAN access on port 80 and the httpd.conf file to change document root.

I've installed Apache before(on Fedora), but didn't have this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. I found a sll.conf file that contains all of the SSL configuration lines. The SSL was enabled by default, its weird. It is located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ and a simple

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine off
</VirtualHost>
```

did the trick.